# How do I delete time values from Pandas DateTime Index?

Tags: python, pandas

Reading from cvs file.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=";", names=['DateTime','Open','High','Low','Close','Vol'],
                 parse_dates = [0], index_col = 'DateTime')
```

Output data:

```
                            Open     High      Low    Close
DateTime                                                     
2016-01-03 00:00:00+00:00  1.08701  1.08723  1.08451  1.08515
2016-01-04 00:00:00+00:00  1.08701  1.09464  1.07811  1.08239
2016-01-05 00:00:00+00:00  1.08238  1.08388  1.07106  1.07502
2016-01-06 00:00:00+00:00  1.07504  1.07994  1.07185  1.07766
2016-01-07 00:00:00+00:00  1.07767  1.09401  1.07710  1.09256
2016-01-08 00:00:00+00:00  1.09255  1.09300  1.08030  1.09218
```

How do I delete time values from above DateTime Index?

Another question, how do I truncate values in Open/High/Low/Close to 6 decimals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To truncate theo datetime, first get the objects into a DateTime object as it does the appropriate handling for this. For example, while printing it will only print the date values as time is always 0.

```
>>> c = pd.read_csv("a.csv", sep=",", names=['DateTime','Open','High','Low','Close','Vol'])
>>> c
                    DateTime     Open     High      Low    Close  Vol
0  2016-01-03 00:00:00+00:00  1.08701  1.08723  1.08451  1.08515  NaN
1  2016-01-04 00:00:00+00:00  1.08701  1.09464  1.07811  1.08239  NaN
2  2016-01-05 00:00:00+00:00  1.08238  1.08388  1.07106  1.07502  NaN
3  2016-01-06 00:00:00+00:00  1.07504  1.07994  1.07185  1.07766  NaN
4  2016-01-07 00:00:00+00:00  1.07767  1.09401  1.07710  1.09256  NaN
5  2016-01-08 00:00:00+00:00  1.09255  1.09300  1.08030  1.09218  NaN
>>> c.DateTime = pd.to_datetime(c.DateTime)
>>> c
    DateTime     Open     High      Low    Close  Vol
0 2016-01-03  1.08701  1.08723  1.08451  1.08515  NaN
1 2016-01-04  1.08701  1.09464  1.07811  1.08239  NaN
2 2016-01-05  1.08238  1.08388  1.07106  1.07502  NaN
3 2016-01-06  1.07504  1.07994  1.07185  1.07766  NaN
4 2016-01-07  1.07767  1.09401  1.07710  1.09256  NaN
5 2016-01-08  1.09255  1.09300  1.08030  1.09218  NaN
```

This would normally save the time also if it is present, it just doesn't show it here because the time values are 0. To only get the date, do:

```
>>> c.DateTime = c.DateTime.dt.date
>>> c.DateTime[0]
datetime.date(2016, 1, 3)
```

Comment: If I have DateTime as index, how do I do it?

Comment: I believe the to_datetime should handle DateTimeIndex too, and convert those to datetime objects. but I may be mistaken. If you'd like more help please provide an example csv to understand better (I've never used DateTimeIndex)